# netbeans 7.1 and python

Tags: python, netbeans, netbeans-7.1

I used to use my Netbeans 6.9 for Python development. As well as Java and PHP. I had a cool debugger in PHP with xDebug, good Python support. Have no complaints whatsoever. I moved to another computer downloaded the latest netbeans(7.1) and now I have no more python plugin. I tried the solution [here](https://techknowhow.library.emory.edu/blogs/sturnbu/2011/05/12/netbeans-7-and-python-ide) but this caused NetBeans not to start at all after the loading splash screen is finished NetBeans crashes.

Is there any way I can still code in Python with netbeans?
Thank you in advance

Comment: I know you like NetBeans but PYCHARM RULEZ!

Answer (score 8):

Ok, I fixed this. Say you've screwed up your netbeans installation by installing the pythonplugin then this might just work for you, provided you're using a non-windows OS. This is because Windows uses precompiled binaries to start the Netbeans IDE.

The problem that I solved is that, by default, a set of classes is not added to the Java classpath, which results in a crash. You can find whether this is also your problem by inspecting .netbeans//var/log/messages. If it displays some ClassNotFoundExceptions then we might have the same problem. If not, then at least you've got some pointers on what's going wrong and perhaps you might come up with some solution yourself. ;)

The java classpath is constructed in the file:

```
/<path>/<to>/<your>/<netbeans>/<installation>/platform/lib/nbexec
```

On OSX, this could be:

```
/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.1.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib
```

In the main loop the function construct_classpath is called, which in turn calls the function build_classpath for two directories. I changed the function to this:

```
build_cp() {
    base="$1"
    append_jars_to_cp "${base}/lib/patches" "patches"
    append_jars_to_cp "${base}/lib" "lib"
    append_jars_to_cp "${base}/lib/locale" "locale"
    # Added by me:
    append_jars_to_cp "${base}/modules/ext" "ext"
}
```

After that modification, start your IDE and everything should work fine. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I've cleaned up the instructions in your answer.

Comment: Perfect, used in MacOSX with netbeans 7.2.1, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The Solution for this problem could be found here

http://sahanlm.blogspot.com/2012/12/netbeans-7-2-crash-on-start.html

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using the developer plugins on Netbeans 7.0.1 with no problem. Maybe they simply aren't compatible with the new version yet. I'd suggest just getting a 7.0 and using that.

Comment: I experienced the same when I tried to install it in Netbeans 7.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Add `org.eclipse.osgi_3.7.1.R37x_v20110808-1106.jar` at
`C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.1.1\platform\lib\locale`. Start NetBeans, remove the plugin or the reference with problem, later on, delete `org.eclipse.osgi_3.7.1.R37x_v20110808-1106.jar`

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change `nbexec`, like suggested by Bas Jacobs (e.g. on Windows), or don't want to do that, you can use the `--cp:p` startup parameter to append the necessary JARs to the classpath.

I only had to add the `org.eclipse.osgi_3.7.1.R37x_v20110808-1106.jar` file, so the complete command line under windows now looks like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.1\bin\netbeans.exe" --cp:a C:\\Users\\_YOUR_USERNAME_\\.netbeans\7.1\modules\ext\org.eclipse.osgi_3.7.1.R37x_v20110808-1106.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following link. It works for me:

http://wiki.netbeans.org/PythonInstall

Answer (score 0):

Currently your NetBeans/Python choices are:

- Try the latest development build updates against your current NetBeans version and mess with breakage at times as noted on the [PythonInstall](http://wiki.netbeans.org/PythonInstall) NetBeans wiki page or the link you gave.
- Install the [latest development version](http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/), but realize it's not a stable public release.
- Wait for someone in the community to step up with continued development to keep the existing plugin in step with the latest public NetBeans release.
- Install the NetBeans 6.9 (or older) version you were using with no complaints just for Python work.

I have had success with older versions and the development build. I am dabbling with other Python aware IDEs while I wait for main stream support, but I've stopped holding my breath.