# Netbeans 7.1 won't run after installing python 

Tags: python, netbeans, ide, netbeans-7

I have just installed python in nb7.1  using http://deadlock.netbeans.org/hudson/job/nbms-and-javadoc/lastStableBuild/artifact/nbbuild/nbms/updates.xml.gz  and and it doesn't show up.

I want to turn some plug-ins of from its home dir. How can I achieve this?

then I read on NB Forums (http://forums.netbeans.org/post-124523.html#115641), I found this guys saying
"Dont do this step it will crash Netbeans" 
But no one is telling how to reverse this.

**EDIT**

here is the log output

```
WARNING [org.netbeans.core.modules]: had to upgrade dependencies for module net.sf.efhnbm: added = [module org.openide.awt, module org.openide.options > 6.7, module org.openide.util.lookup > 8.0] removed = []; details: [#170056: Separate module for Lookup API, #88531 Remove SystemOption usage from PrintSettings, SaveCookie extends Savable. To compile you need to include openide.awt on classpath.]
WARNING [org.netbeans.core.modules]: had to upgrade dependencies for module org.netbeans.modules.selenium.php: added = [module org.openide.awt] removed = []; details: [SaveCookie extends Savable. To compile you need to include openide.awt on classpath.]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/osgi/framework/startlevel/BundleStartLevel while loading org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle; see http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqTroubleshootClassNotFound
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.selfLoadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:304)
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:227)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.EquinoxLauncher.internalInit(EquinoxLauncher.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.EquinoxLauncher.init(EquinoxLauncher.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.init(Equinox.java:178)
    at org.netbeans.modules.netbinox.Netbinox.init(Netbinox.java:75)
    at org.netbeans.core.netigso.Netigso.prepare(Netigso.java:149)
    at org.netbeans.NetigsoFramework.turnOn(NetigsoFramework.java:214)
    at org.netbeans.ModuleManager.enable(ModuleManager.java:1087)
    at org.netbeans.ModuleManager.enable(ModuleManager.java:906)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList.installNew(ModuleList.java:340)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList.trigger(ModuleList.java:276)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleSystem.restore(ModuleSystem.java:294)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.getModuleSystem(Main.java:169)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.start(Main.java:305)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.TopThreadGroup.run(TopThreadGroup.java:123)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/osgi/framework/startlevel/BundleStartLevel
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at org.netbeans.JarClassLoader.doLoadClass(JarClassLoader.java:266)
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.selfLoadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:300)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.osgi.framework.startlevel.BundleStartLevel starting from ModuleCL@57f530d8[org.netbeans.modules.netbinox] with possible defining loaders null and declared parents [ModuleCL@4145f572[org.netbeans.core.netigso], org.netbeans.MainImpl$BootClassLoader@18b753f8, ModuleCL@65cc892e[org.netbeans.libs.osgi]]
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:264)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.osgi.framework.startlevel.BundleStartLevel
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:262)
    ... 23 more
```

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

I found the blasted plugin under Users\$MyUser$\AppData\Roaming\Netbeans\7.2

Made special note of (read: deleted) files in Python-sounding directories that matched the time I ran into the startup problem. Netbeans ran fine afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

At least in my case it was the addition of the "development update center" which broke netbeans and not the python plugin itself. See post https://stackoverflow.com/a/9993301/970910 for a possible fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove the plugin manually :

> Go in your home, there is a **.netbeans** directory. Go inside and delete the plugins files here.

http://forums.netbeans.org/post-78253.html&highlight=

Comment: I don't think its a good idea because i have my version control installed there. and I don't want to mess with my local history etc.

Can you please suggest something  less destructive?

Comment: You can just delete the directory that contains the plugin python and not the whole directory.

Comment: Ok, I just moved the .netbeans folder and started netbeans but it didn't show up?

Comment: You need the directory I think, delete everything inside is a bad idea. Can you identify where files specific to python plugin are and delete only those?

Comment: Please check the log contents, can you figure out what does it mean?
regards

Comment: You seems to have delete too much files. I don't know exactly what are the python plugin files... you have to find out and drop only those. Sorry can't help more.

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite your netbeans with a new install, better upgrade your netbeans(latest version) with a fresh install, keeping old one there. Then uninstall your old copy it will keep your project untouched.

If you want to keep netbeans7.1 then just overwrite and then remove the plugin using netbeans builtin plugin manager.